# IP and .onion addresses in buckets

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development, tor

From my understanding, the new tables have 1024 buckets and each bucket can hold a maximum of 64 addresses. Is there a limit set in place for the maximum number of address types that can be part of the 64 addresses? For example, a threshold of 30 .onion addresses of the maximum 64 addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such thresholds. All types of IP addresses are treated equally.

Comment: Just so there is no ambiguity, you mean all types of **addresses**?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I try to avoid the term "address" as it can be confused with Bitcoin addresses. But I mean IP, onion, I2P, CJDNS addresses are all treated equally.